# Conversion between char and wchar_t in NDK

Tags: c, android-ndk, chat, wchar-t

Assume:

```
char from[10]="abcd";
wchar_t to[10]=L"";
```

In gcc under Linux and MSVC, I can use: `sscanf(from, "%S", to);` to get a `wchar_t` string `L"abcd"` in `to`. But this does not work in NDK.

I want to know whether this is supported in NDK? Is there any alternatives?

I know I can use a copy loop to accomplish this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(from); ++i)
    to[i] = from[i];
```

I'm using android-ndk-r7-crystax-5.beta2-linux-x86.tar.bz2 . My string contains only ASCII characters, so I'm don't want use `iconv`.

Comment: See the [`mbstowcs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) function.

Answer (score 0):

google android ndk said:support wchar function。but some wchar function just provided empty.
such as:`wsclen()`, always return 1.
you can use http://www.crystax.net/ ndk,